# youtubeAPI v3 invalid certificate on tvOS

Tags: ssl, swift2, nsurlsession, tvos, youtube-data-api

I want to request the youtube-data-api v3 from my tvOS App. To do so I wrote the following class:

```
class YoutubeSearch {

static let sharedClient = YoutubeSearch()
private var task: NSURLSessionDataTask!


    func getVideoNSURLsForTitle(title: String, completionHandler: ([String], NSError?) -> Void ) -> NSURLSessionTask {

        // URL
        let urlString = makeURL(title)
        let url = NSURL(string: youtubeApi)

        // cancel task, if there is already one
        task?.cancel()

        // setup new request
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)
        task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            // No errors occured
            do {

            // some JSON processing
            // complitionHandler is returned here

            } catch let parseError {
                // Some other error
                print(parseError)
                let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                print("YoutubeSearch Error: '\(jsonStr)'")
            }

        }

        // execute request
        task.resume()
        return task
    }
}
```

The code works fine in the simulator. I get a valid JSON. But on tvOS it throws an error telling me the certificate is invalid:

> NSUnderlyingError=0x13e207d70 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1202 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerTrust=, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9814, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9814, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerCertificates={type = immutable, count = 3, values = (
>       0 : 
>       1 : 
>       2 : 
>   )}}}, NSLocalizedDescription=The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “www.googleapis.com” which could put your confidential information at risk., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?videoEmbeddable=true&videoType=any&videoDefinition=any&order=relevance&part=snippet&videoDimension=any&q=lets+play+berlin&videoCaption=closedCaption&videoLicense=any&videoSyndicated=true&type=video&videoDuration=short&maxResults=10&key={API-KEY}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?videoEmbeddable=true&videoType=any&videoDefinition=any&order=relevance&part=snippet&videoDimension=any&q=lets+play+berlin&videoCaption=closedCaption&videoLicense=any&videoSyndicated=true&type=video&videoDuration=short&maxResults=10&key={API-KEY}, NSErrorClientCertificateStateKey=0})

Yet I wasn't able to nail down the problem. I found Apples Technical Note TN2232 on HTTPS Server Trust Evaluation, but frankly said much to work through while I'm not sure if I just forgot about a simple additional thing.

I've learned that I could disable server trust. But this is not an option for me as the app is supposed to apply at the Apple Store.

Does anybody faced the same problem? Or does anybody have a clue on what to do in order to solve the problem?

Kind regards!